# Chrome hanging up computer (OSX)

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, freeze

In last month I'm having big problems with Chrome on my Mac (Mavericks 10.9.4)... after some time (a day, sometimes a few hours), I get hangs and I barely manage to launch a system Force Quit Applications menu with alt+cmd+esc and quit Chrome... sometimes I cannot even do that and I have to shutdown the computer.

There is a evidence in Console that something is wrong:

[image]

I tried to recreate my user profile, didn't help...

This is driving me really mad. Could it possibly be one of my extensions - can I debug this?

Comment: You created a new user profile.  you used the term "recreate" which indicates you used a saved profile and/or synced settings.

Comment: I deleted the profile folder and started from scratch.. then I signed in and got my extension and I set them up anew.